# Why is this condition sufficient for the space to be Lindelöf?

Tags: general-topology, lindelof-spaces

This is the definition of a Lindelöf space:

> A space for which every open covering contains a countable subcovering
> is a Lindelöf space.

In the proof that $\mathbb{R}_l$ is Lindelöf, they have this statement:

> It will suffice to show that every open covering of $\mathbb{R}_l$ by
> basis elements contains a countable subcovering of $\mathbb{R}_l$.

But I can not see why:

My attempt at proof:

Let $\{O_a\}$ be an open covering, set $A=\cup O_a$. A must be open. For each $x \in A$, there is a basis element such that $x \in B_x\in A$. But the problem is that for $x \in A^c$, $A^c$ is closed, so how do we handle these elements? I can not conclude that we have a countable covering of A, since even though we have basis elements covering A, these elements may not cover the entire space $\mathbb{R}_l$?

Comment: Would you like it if someone misspelled your name?

Comment: You can restrict to basic open sets in the definition of Lindelöf, for any space $X$. A cover by open sets induces a cover by basic open sets, since any open set can be written as a union of basic sets.

Comment: But I don't get what you mean by $A$. If $(O_a)_a$ is a covering, shouldn't this $A$ be the entire space?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Honestly, I wouldn't care.

Answer (score 2):

Given an open covering $\{O_a\}$ we can write each $O_a$ as union of basis elements, $O_a=\bigcup_{i\in I_a}B_{\langle a,i\rangle}$. Then $A$ is also covered by all those $B_{\langle a,i\rangle}$. If we can find a countable subcover $\{\,B_{\langle a_n,i_n\rangle}\mid n\in\Bbb N\,\}$ then certainly $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}O_{a_n}$ covers $A$.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that the hypothesis says you can only find a countable subcover if the space happens to be the entire $\mathbb{R}_l$?